# Custom JSON in Highmaps

Tags: json, highcharts, highmaps

I was mocking up a map with specific countries highlighted in the Fixed Tooltip with HTML map. I edited the JSON, validated it, and hosted it at myjSON. As you can see, that first version worked: http://jsfiddle.net/katwood/2ppqpm8n/

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/652m1', function (data) {

// Add lower case codes to the data set for inclusion in the tooltip.pointFormat
$.each(data, function () {
    this.flag = this.code.replace('UK', 'GB').toLowerCase();
});

// Initiate the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
```

When my data became more solid, I added a few more countries to the JSON, validated that one, and hosted it at myJSON again. However, when I add the new URI for the new JSON, the whole thing fails: http://jsfiddle.net/katwood/2ppqpm8n/10/

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gv4ut', function(data) {
```

I just changed the URI, but other than that, everything's the same. What happened?

Comment: `{"code ": "SG ", "value ": 2, "name ": "Singapore "}` ruined it. No `code` property. Check console.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was one of those cases where I had stared at the code for so long, I didn't see the bonus spaces. Much appreciated!